# Getting submissions from Reddit

Tags: ajax, reddit

my current problem is that in trying to get the top posts from a subreddit, I am instead receiving the Hot posts in said subreddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/top.json?limit=100 for me returns the top 100 posts in the gaming subreddit, but for a friend this will return the 100 "hottest" posts in the subreddit. When i use ajax to get the data using this URL I am also receiving the Hot posts. Is this a common issue? Any help resolving it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sample responses (ideally, with limit=1) would be helpful. If I had to guess, based on my knowledge of the reddit API and the fact that you're seeing different results from different users, you're hitting the case where each user has a different default time-scale for their top sort.

When visiting https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/top (or any listing that has a drop-down menu to indicate time-scale), whenever the user changes that time-scale (say, from "all time" to "today"), the default time-scale for that user is set to the new value.

API clients should explicitly send the `t` (time) query parameter (except in cases where the API client wants to make use of the user's default `t` parameter); e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/top.json?t=all.

For a list of values that the `t` parameter accepts, see [the API documentation for /top](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_top)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the problem I'm having. I just tested this against some data, comparing the top posts of the last day to the current /Hot stream and the data I'm getting is definitely from /Hot. Sample responses aren't really necessary, what's happening is that I'm asking for top.json and getting hot.json in the call for some reason.

Comment: Sample data would definitely help. That said, when I check, I can't reproduce. What I see in incognito windows is the same as above - the top posts from today (yes, top, not hot - comparing to the hot list, the ordering is distinctly different). Without more info, I can only assume that you're hitting the `t` parameter issue described. If you're still seeing "hot" data when specifying, e.g., `t=all`, then please add that info to your original question.